# Dominated convergence theorem for function with complex values

Tags: real-analysis

My question is the following :

If I admit the dominated convergence theorem for function with real values, can I deduce from it that it also works for function with complex values (or it can't be proved from this) ?

Indeed, if I write $ f_n=f_n^{real}+i f_n^{imag}$.

And I have $$lim_n \int f_n(x) dx$$

If I use the theorem for function with real values, I need to show that :
$$|f_n^{real}|<g_1 ~ (1)$$
$$|f_n^{imag}|<g_2 ~ (2)$$

Where $g_1$ and $g_2$ are integrable functions.

But showing that isn't equivalent to directly showing : $|f_n|<g ~ (3)$ with $g$ integrable (if I can proove (1) and (2), then I have (3) but to have (3) is not sufficient to have (1) and (2))..

So my question is : the theorem used with functions of complex values can't be derived from the one with real values ?

Comment: It also works the same way for any function with values in a finite dimensional real (normed) vector space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(3) is indeed sufficient for (1) and (2). Note that $|f_n^{real}|\leq|f_n|\leq g$ and also $|f_n^{imag}|\leq|f_n|\leq g$.

Comment: Of course... Thank you !